# How to add the following styles as props for this Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I add the following styles as props for the component?

```
        <template>
        <div>
            <transition-group name='fade' tag='div'>
             ...
          </div>
        </template>

        <script>
        export default {
          name: 'Slider',
          data() {
            return {

            }
      props: { intervalVal: Number,
               width...
 },
          },
        </script>

    styles>

div {
width: 100% 
height: 600px
}

.prev,
.next {
color #fffff
background-color:#22222
```

How can I put that divs with and height as props as well as prev. .next class color and background-colors?

Answer (score 0):

when you only want to style your tag with the prop i would do it with

```
<div :style="`width: ${this.width}`">
```

If you want to add css classes dynamically you can use objects for it like described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

in your template

```
<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>
```

and in your component

```
data: {
  isActive: true,
  hasError: false
}
```

you can also use computed propteries to do it dynamically

Comment: Is the first option that you explained better option than just overwriting default styles in the components where you import this component?

Comment: the first option you can use to pass in (or compute) dynamic values for a certain style.